# How to hide tooltips with their respective dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using charts.js. For my current need, I managed to find a way to configure tooltips to be always visible regardless of the hover event. My problem is that the tooltip visibility does not follow the dataset behaviour. On charts.js, you can click on a dataset in order to remove it from the graph. My graph does that, but the tooltips are still there visible, floating within the graph with no dataset to represent. Is there a way to hide then with the dataset data when the label is clicked ?

Here is an example of the current state of what i said. https://jsfiddle.net/CaioSantAnna/ddejheg0/ .

HTML

```
<canvas id="linha"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
Chart.plugins.register({
    beforeRender: function (chart) {
        if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
            // create an array of tooltips
            // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
            chart.pluginTooltips = [];
            chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (sector, j) {
                    chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                        _chart: chart.chart,
                        _chartInstance: chart,
                        _data: chart.data,
                        _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                        _active: [sector]
                    }, chart));
                });
            });

            // turn off normal tooltips
            chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
        }
    },
    afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
        if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
            // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
            if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
                if (easing !== 1)
                    return;
                chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
            }

            // turn on tooltips
            chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
            Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function (tooltip) {
                tooltip.initialize();
                tooltip.update();
                // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
                tooltip.pivot();
                tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
            });
            chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
        }
    }
});

ctx = document.getElementById("linha");
    var linha = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fill: true,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                    borderDash: [],
                    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                    pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointRadius: 1,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                    spanGaps: false,
                    responsive: true,
                    animation: true,
                },
                {
                    label: "Second dataset",
                    fill: true,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
                    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                    borderDash: [],
                    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                    pointBorderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointRadius: 1,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    data: [13, 78, 60, 75, 90, 10, 27],
                    spanGaps: false,
                    responsive: true,
                    animation: true,
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    title: function (tooltipItem, data) { return "" },
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        var value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                        var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || 'Other';
                        var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                        return value;
                    }
                }
            },showAllTooltips: true
        }
    });
```

To reproduce the problem, just click in one of the labels on the top of the graph.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question, I ended up changing to amcharts(https://www.amcharts.com/). It has features like the one i was trying to achieve with chart.js and is free to use under a linkware license.

Thanks again.